# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'qgis' MacOS

Tags: pyqgis, mac, pycharm

trying to setup pycharm for QGIS development in MacOS. I added to the interpreter path the QGIS bin path  /Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/bin but still no luck.
All the guides I find are for windows.

```
    from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QSettings, QTranslator, QCoreApplication
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'qgis'
```

Any suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Before executing your python code, export the QGIS Python path:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/Resources/python
```

if QGIS is installed in the default path.